# PHP - Receber o ID de um valor via select option $_POST

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa tarde pessoal, eu to desenvolvendo um código e empaquei numa parte.

Eu preciso obter um valor para registra-lo como fkid de uma tabela.

Eu tenho essa parte do codigo:

```
    <td><h3>Vincular Conteudo</h3></td>
    <td colspan="2"><select name="tipoConteudo" class="form-control">
    <?php
        $tipoConteudo = new ConteudoDAO($conexao);
        foreach($tipoConteudo->listaNomeConteudo() as $tipo) : 
    ?>
            <option value="<?=$tipo['nomeConteudo']?>"> 
                <?=$tipo['nomeConteudo']; ?> 
            </option> 
        <?php 
        endforeach
        ?>
```

Essa parte do codigo funciona perfeitamente. Ele demonstra um dropdown do que eu preciso. Mas eu preciso enviar o id vinculado ao "nomeConteudo" , que pertence a tabela conteudo. Vou demonstrar a função listaNomeConteudo a baixo:

```
function listaNomeConteudo() {
    $conteudos = array();
    $query = "select * from conteudo";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);

   while($conteudo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        array_push($conteudos, $conteudo);
    }
    return $conteudos;
}
```

Tudo que eu preciso é pegar o ID da linha nomeConteudo, e vincular numa nova tabela como fkid.

Alguém conseguiria me ajudar? Obrigaod

Comment: Vale ressalvar que quando eu tento pegar o valor por post de tipoConteudo, ele retorna apenas "ARRAY"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nessa parte:

```
<option value="<?=$tipo['nomeConteudo']?>"> 
                <?=$tipo['nomeConteudo']; ?> 
            </option>
```

Por que você está passando 'nomeConteudo' no value? Porque não passa o ID?

Comment: Cara, sabe aquele momento em que você olha seu código e parece que tá tudo certo? Realmente, resolveu meu problema. Obrigado.

Comment: Acontece. Já rolou muitas vezes comigo haha. Se puder, só favorita minha resposta. Abraços!

Comment: @AndréMolinari pelo que percebi a resposta do Cayo está correta. Apenas você pode marca-la como uma resposta certa.